# touchesBegan and responders in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitouch, touchesbegan

How can I add an event recognizer to an object?

I have the following code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
NSLog(@"touches happened");


    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.mainView];

    for (UIView *view in self.mainView.subviews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[ViewController class]] &&
            CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, touchLocation))
        {
            NSLog(@"my Touch Happened");
            UIImageView *tmp = (UIImageView *)view;
            if (selectedItem != tmp)
                [self setSelected:tmp];

        }
    }
}
```

My goal is, if my image is touched, not tapped or long pressed but touched at all, to do the logic starting at the `NSLog(@"found whats being touched");`

I;ve use UIGestureRecognizers before and you add them to whatever you want.

[self.SomeImage addGestureRecognizer:rotate];

But how do I tell my objects to listen to this code?

I wanna know if the touched area is the same area that another object exists in? that is, if the user is trying to pan an item. I can handle the pan. But the second before the pan is the touch. How Do I go about finding that touch and the object that is associated with that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIViewController and UIView directly supports `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

You can directly put your function inside such objects. (i.e UIView or UIViewController)